# error while inputing an csv file into java code

Tags: java, csv, converters, xls

the question is how can i use java to input a csv file and output an xls file 
is there any specefic api or lib which can help question gonna help so why it s error on opening a sheet

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
    workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

after i tried i think it s due to a memor problem  idk

Comment: You expect that code to parse the CSV and turn it into an Excel workbook? Not even close.

Comment: what you propose ? am newbie and i really want to know

Comment: Apache POI will not parse your CSV. It gives you just enough support to create an Excel file when you precisely and explicitly tell it what to put into each cell, including the data type. So you'll need to parse the CSV on your own (or using the `opencsv` library) and have code which fills the Excel worksheet.